# Is any font that looks like LED in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am develop a simple iPhone app. I need a font that looks like LED. 
Is any font that looks like LED in iPhone ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to try "DBLCDTempBlack"

A list of available fonts can be found here: 
http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is the "DB LCD Temp Black" font.

In code, its name is "DBLCDTempBlack".

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:yoursize]
```

Comment: Any idea why it's not showing up in the Interface Builder font list?

Comment: @Clafou, I think it's no longer a pre-installed font in iOS 6

Comment: Right, it's not in IOS 6 anymore. Apple has now a page showing all the fonts included in iOS 6: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5484